# How to pass "applied function" as a parameter in Common Lisp

Tags: clojure, lisp, common-lisp

I am new to Common Lisp, and am trying to implement a `repeatedly` from Clojure. For example

```lisp
(repeatedly 5 #(rand-int 11))
```

This will collect 5 (rand-int 11) calls, and return a list:
`(10 1 3 0 2)`

Currently, this is what I'm doing:

```lisp
(defun repeatedly (n f args)
  (loop for x from 1 to n
       collect (apply f args)))
```

Which doesn't look as nice, I have to call it like this: `(repeatedly 5 #'random '(11))`. Is there a way to make the function more intuitive, as in Clojure's syntax?

The code can then get pretty ugly: `(repeatedly 5 #'function (list (- x 1)))`.

https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/repeatedly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but maybe just something like this:

```
(defun repeatedly (n function)
  (loop repeat n collect (funcall function)))
```

Since `#(…)` is just a shorthand for lambdas in Clojure.

```
CL-USER> (repeatedly 5 (lambda () (random 11)))
(0 8 3 6 2)
```

But this is even a bit shorter:

```
CL-USER> (loop repeat 5 collect (random 11))
(5 4 6 2 3)
```

Comment: Thanks, you understood, that's what I wanted. So what makes it compact is the syntactic sugar Clojure has, but using lambda is indeed clearer than the way I was doing.

Comment: @PedroQueiroga See https://github.com/cbaggers/fn for an existing shorter syntax for anonymous functions (but keep in mind warnings from Rainer Joswig)

Answer (score 6):

While Daniels answer perfect, I'd like to point out a cool thing about CL. You can implement a similar reader macro as Clojure has. Now since `#(1 2 3)` is a array literal in CL I'll implement `[...]` with both `[...]` and `#(...)` features.

```lisp
(set-macro-character #\[
  (lambda (stream char)
    (declare (ignore char))
    (let ((body (read-delimited-list #\] stream t)))
      `(lambda (&optional %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 &aux (_ %1)) ,body))))

(set-macro-character #\]
  (get-macro-character #\)))
```

I didn't take the time to search for the `%s` and `_` so it isn't optimal. Here are some examples:

```lisp
(mapcar [sqrt (+ (* %1 %1) (* %2 %2))] '(1 3 5) '(2 4 6))
; ==> (2.236068 5 7.81025)
(mapcar [* _ 2] '(2 4 6))    
; ==> (4 8 12)
(repeatedly 5 [rand-int 11]) 
; ==> (10 1 3 0 2)
```

Answer (score 6):

**Rest args**

One can write it also as

```
(defun repeatedly (n f &rest args)
  (loop repeat n collect (apply f args)))
```

Thus there is no need to create the argument list yourself.

Then one calls it:

```
> (repeatedly 5 #'random (1- x))
(7 2 3 1 4)
```

instead of `(repeatedly 5 #'random (list (1- x)))`

**shorter notation via macros**

short lambda notations can also be achieved via macros for some purposes:

```
> (defun repeatedly (n function)
    (loop repeat n collect (funcall function)))
REPEATEDLY

> (repeatedly 5 (lambda () (random 10)))
(1 7 1 7 8)

> (defmacro ⧨ (&body body) `(lambda () ,@body))
⧨

> (repeatedly 5 (⧨ (random 10)))
(9 3 0 7 0)

or alternatively:

> (defmacro ⧩ (&body body) `(lambda () ,body))
⧩

> (repeatedly 5 (⧩ random 10))
(9 7 7 7 5)
```

**style**

Often it is also not necessary nor desirable to write language constructs as *reader macros*. The extension of s-expressions is best left below the programming language level -> s-expressions are mostly a data syntax.

In most Lisp code one actually finds `lambda` expressions used without any abbreviation. The usual Lisp style is to use symbolic names and not so much special characters or special lexical/token syntax. It makes the text slightly longer, but has other advantages. For example one sees the same `lambda` in text and in the read or even running code...